# Lightning - Navigate to record created from helper js

Tags: lightning-apps, navigation

I am trying to navigate to the newly inserted record from lightning app. Note- we have not used lightning component instead we used lighting app. The record is getting inserted in Controller method which is called from helper. Any way I can navigate the user to the created record.

Note - The current setup is passing the record id to windows location  Getting error -  Refused to display 'https://mydomain-v2.my.salesforce.com/00Q1N00000ghrFLUAY' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
Ajax.js:109 HTTP-Based Public Key Pinning is deprecated. Chrome 69 and later will ignore HPKP response headers.

Comment: Salesforce documention; https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one_demo_fire.htm?search_text=force:navigateToSObject

Comment: please share the code you are trying to navigate with

Answer (score 1):

**Events Handled in the Salesforce mobile app and Lightning Experience**

The Salesforce app and Lightning Experience handle some events, which you can fire in your Lightning component.

> If you fire one of these force or lightning events in your Lightning
>   apps or components outside of the Salesforce app or Lightning
>   Experience: You must handle the event by using the aura:handler tag
>   in the handling component.

Use the aura:registerEvent or aura:dependency tags to ensure that the event is sent to the client when needed.

> Must note that that certain platform (so called one.app container)
>   features are not available in standalone Apps, events such as
>   navigateToSObject or showToast will not work there

Reference:-

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_one.htm

[Lightning application vs Lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200698/lightning-application-vs-lightning-component)